# Jersey & Jackson date format issues

Tags: json, jackson, jersey, jax-rs

I am having some issues getting deserializing JSON date with Jersey & Jackson

I have a class, e.g Item:

```
public class Item {
    @JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="yyyy-MM-dd")
    private Date itemDate;

    // other String values and getters/setters
}
```

The endpoint is as follows:

```
@Path("/createItem")
@POST
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response newItem(Item i) {
    System.out.println(i.getItemDate());
}
```

If I POST the following JSON data

```
{
    "itemDate": "2015-03-01"
}
```

`i.getItemDate()` is always returning null. Unless I use the default date format `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'` I was trying to change the format to `yyyy-MM-dd` but I am unable to do this. I have tried `@JsonDeserialize` with a custom class as per examples on this site.

It's also worth noting that when using the custom @JsonDeserializer it would never hit any break-point in the custom class, like it was ignoring the annotations e.g

```
 @JsonDeserialiser(using = MyCustomDateFormat.class)
```

If I have a break point in `CustomJsonDateDeserializer` it never gets hit.

```
public class CustomJsonDateDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Date> {
    @Override
    public Date deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser,
                            DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException {

        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        String date = jsonParser.getText();
        try {
            return format.parse(date);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

    }
}
```

Do I need to do something else to register the deserialization handler, or should it work with one of the approaches above?

Comment: What the version of `Jackson` do you use? Which version: `FasterXML` or `codehaus`?

Comment: Are you sue you're even using Jackson as your JSON provider? Can you show your project dependencies? Also what server are you using?

Comment: I am using glassfish 4. I have all the dependencies on the project but maybe I haven't set something up properly in order to register them for use. I will show dependencies tomorrow, I'm not at work at the moment. 'FasterXML'  seems familiar I've seen that in some of the imports. Apologies I am still learning about this.

Comment: The default provider in Glassfish 4 is MOXy, not Jackson. You need to add the jersey-media-json-jackson dependency to your project (in a provided scope) and then register the `JacksonFeature`. This will allow you to use Jackson.